# What does if I put an ID to linking the CSS file?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to say that what will happen if I put an ID between the CSS linking tag? Like the below:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='base.css-css'  href=''>
```

What does the ID actually there?

I didn't understand it actually and never saw it before anywhere. I saw one of Developer made a Template like this.

Please, help me anyone with this?

Comment: This is not part of any standard or custom I'm aware of; it won't do anything specific. The `href=''` looks plain wrong though (as it points to the current URL).  I'd ask the developer what this is about. Maybe they're doing some JavaScript shenanigans with it but I'd bet a beer what they're doing is bad practice then

Comment: It doesn't *do* anything, but neither does an id in any other element do anything by itself. It's possible that the templating engine uses it to determine how to modify the tag before outputting the final HTML.

Comment: "I am trying to say that what will happen..." Why don't you just try it then? `id` is a global attribute and can be applied to any tag. `<link>` can still be accessed as a node in the DOM... referencing it by ID would make that easier.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your useful answer. Yes, the Developer added lot of Javascript file because the template included many transition and animation. Please, check this template source code and then reply me what you understand and what do you suggest me to using it? http://bookofpixels.com/iconik/

Answer (score 2):

The element will have an id.

This will make it addressable by the id. e.g. from JavaScript/DOM `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Hi,
This is a nice answer to me. But, what will happen if I don't use the ID. Is this will affect anything? What's the benefit for make it addressable by the ID actually?

Comment: @SumonKhan If you're not even going to use the id, why do you care? Just install the theme as per the author's instructions and stop worrying.

Comment: Dear @Juhana
Thank you for your reply. I do care. I've to know this that why and how this works actually? Can you please tell me too If I don't use the ID then what will happen? Is this gonna affect something to the Theme?

Comment: Nothing is going to happen.

Comment: @Juhana
If nothing is going to happen then why he used it? I think, of-course there is something going to happen. But, don't know what it will be :O

Comment: *Then don't remove them.*

Comment: @Juhana
Then how I will understand why he put this and what's exactly work with this?

Answer (score 0):

look i think this is not part of any standard but if think of it as puzzle you can understand it like this:

1. `href=''` href is empty which may mean that the resource we are talking about is located under the root directly.(it's equivalent to '/').
2. `id='base.css-css'` i think it's telling you which resource we are talking about. it's about css file called `base.css-css`

Comment: Hi,
Actually href='' isn't empty. I wrote it empty here. If this telling me that which resource it's talking about then I can easily understood it to see the href='' source. What does it actually?

Comment: from @Quentin answer i think you can use the id attribute to get the link as Dom-Element then when you have it you can get it's all attributes(and from it you can read href that may tell the resource file)

Comment: It seems like a good answers to me!

Comment: if it helped you then i guess i deserve upvote at leaset

Comment: Yeah, But I couldn't because my reputation is enough to do that :)

Comment: @SumonKhan upvote dose not take any points from you. read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work